# How to use the expression 一個上年

Tags: meaning, usage

My book, among other expressions we should read out, lists 一個上年 without explanation. Now, I have heard 上年 as a variant of 去年，but I can't guess the meaning of 一個上年！ I can't imagine when you would want to use this, since "last year" is unambiguous. There are no choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, **年** here was a typo of **午** in your book.

一個上午 (a morning) make sense; 一個上年(a last year ) doesn't make sense.

- '**A** year' can be any **unspecific** year
- '**Last** year' is a **specific** year in the context of the speech.
- The phrase '一個上年' (a last year) contradicts itself.

Another explanation for '一個上年' to exist could be: '**上**年' here doesn't mean '**last** year', but '**good** year'( 上 as in 上等 - high quality). That is also unlikely, because '一個**好**年'is much more common way to describe a '**good** year'

If 一個上年 was not a typo, then it can only mean '上年'(last year) was a special year that was marked as a particular reference.

For example: "再来一個上年, 公司就要破產 "-- "one more (year like) last year, the company will bankrupt"

Answer (score 1):

Somethings when I play the computer games for a whole morning, my friends would say:  你居然打了一个上午的游戏 ！(you should play the game for for a whole morning), here 一个 was used to emphasis.

Comment: Don't your friends say 一個上天？ But I think you explained the basic point. It seems to mean 一個多年 (2 years or more, according to my feeble knowledge)

Comment: In fact, we don't often use 一个上天,since 上天 means go to the sky rather than yesterday. ps: “一个” means may refers to one or a, depends on different situation. like 一个下午，我遇到了一个以前的朋友( one day afternoon, I came across one of my friend)，the first 一个means one , but not used to emphasis,  we always emphasis when we want to express a whole period of time.

Answer (score 0):

这是个错误的语法！你可以说上一个年头，或者去年，但绝对不可以说上一个年！

This is wrong. You can say "上一个年头" or "去年", but never "上一个年".

Comment: I thingk you meant `绝对`.

Comment: @songyuanyao 手误，sorry